# How do I write a jQuery statement to access a specific DOM element using Chrome Developer Tools? (2 questions in 1)

Tags: jquery, dom, google-chrome-devtools

**Question 1**:
I don't know what to call this row in Chrome Developer Tool but using the tool, I can identify the element I'm looking for (see cursor in image for reference).

[image: I do not know what this row is referred too in Chrome Developer Tools]

**Question 2** (See Image below):
When the page loads, if the menu is open, I'd like to show the correct chevron so I've written:
`$('li.active').find('span.fa-chevron-right.rotate').toggleClass('fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down');` but nothing is happening (no errors and the desired effect is not occurring). Ideally the chevron in the red box should be up and pointed down in the green box when opened.

**UPDATE - ADDING HTML FOR WOW FACTOR**

```
<div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
<div class="menu_section active">
    <h3>General</h3>
    <ul class="nav side-menu" style="">
        <li class="active">
            <a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: block;">
                <li class="current-page"><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="index2.html">Dashboard2</a></li>
                <li><a href="index3.html">Dashboard3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Forms <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                <li><a href="form.html">General Form</a></li>
                <li><a href="form_advanced.html">Advanced Components</a></li>
                <li><a href="form_validation.html">Form Validation</a></li>
                <li><a href="form_wizards.html">Form Wizard</a></li>
                <li><a href="form_upload.html">Form Upload</a></li>
                <li><a href="form_buttons.html">Form Buttons</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> UI Elements <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                <li><a href="general_elements.html">General Elements</a></li>
                <li><a href="media_gallery.html">Media Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="typography.html">Typography</a></li>
                <li><a href="icons.html">Icons</a></li>
                <li><a href="glyphicons.html">Glyphicons</a></li>
                <li><a href="widgets.html">Widgets</a></li>
                <li><a href="invoice.html">Invoice</a></li>
                <li><a href="inbox.html">Inbox</a></li>
                <li><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a><i class="fa fa-table"></i> Tables <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                <li><a href="tables.html">Tables</a></li>
                <li><a href="tables_dynamic.html">Table Dynamic</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Data Presentation <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                <li><a href="chartjs.html">Chart JS</a></li>
                <li><a href="chartjs2.html">Chart JS2</a></li>
                <li><a href="morisjs.html">Moris JS</a></li>
                <li><a href="echarts.html">ECharts</a></li>
                <li><a href="other_charts.html">Other Charts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a><i class="fa fa-clone"></i>Layouts <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                <li><a href="fixed_sidebar.html">Fixed Sidebar</a></li>
                <li><a href="fixed_footer.html">Fixed Footer</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="menu_section">
    <h3>Live On</h3>
    <ul class="nav side-menu">
        <li>
            <a><i class="fa fa-bug"></i> Additional Pages <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                <li><a href="e_commerce.html">E-commerce</a></li>
                <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="project_detail.html">Project Detail</a></li>
                <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a><i class="fa fa-windows"></i> Extras <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                <li><a href="page_403.html">403 Error</a></li>
                <li><a href="page_404.html">404 Error</a></li>
                <li><a href="page_500.html">500 Error</a></li>
                <li><a href="plain_page.html">Plain Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.html">Login Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="pricing_tables.html">Pricing Tables</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> Multilevel Menu <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                <li><a href="#level1_1">Level One</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a>Level One<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav child_menu">
                        <li class="sub_menu"><a href="level2.html">Level Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#level2_1">Level Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#level2_2">Level Two</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#level1_2">Level One</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> Landing Page <span class="label label-success pull-right">Coming Soon</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image: Ideally the chevron in the red box should be up and pointed down in the green box when opened.]

Comment: 2) could be that your code runs too soon.  Either the menu hasn't loaded because your script is too early in the page (eg in the `<head>`) or the menu is late-loaded (eg via ajax or a 3rd party plugin) *after* the page has loaded (and after your code has run).   Or your selectors don't match.  Without HTML, impossible to tell.

Comment: The image should be clickable and will show the full path to the element.

Comment: 1) if your path has an ID in it, use that as a starting point (as IDs *must* be unique) - so `$("#sidebar-menu > .menu_section > .side-menu > li.active > a > span.fa-chevron-right")` or probably just `$(".side-menu .active .fa-chevron-right")`

Comment: `$('.side-menu .active .fa-chevron-right').toggleClass('fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down');` worked like a charm! Make that an answer and I'll mark it correct. Is there a rule when the classes should be connected `.side-menu.active.whatever` vs how you wrote it with spaces `.side-menu .active .whatever`?

Comment: jQuery uses the same selectors as css.  Space `" "` means any descendant, while greater than `>` means a (direct) child.  No space means it has to be the same, eg `<div class="a b">` would be `$(".a.b")`  [more here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Thanks for the response and the `more here` link, I found that very helpful. Don't forget to provide the answer below so I can mark it, sir!